# Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances Optimization Check is disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-reserved-instances

I've been using Trusted Advisor Checks for my account and I've noticed that one of the checks, "Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances Optimization" is disabled and when I look at the description of the check, at the bottom it contains a message "This account is not subscribed to the service(s) required for this check". How can I enable that ?

Answer (score 1):

From [Trusted Advisor | Environment Optimization | AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/trusted-advisor/):

> **Business Support and Enterprise Support customers** get access to the full set of Trusted Advisor checks and recommendations. These help optimize your entire AWS infrastructure, to increase security and performance, reduce your overall costs, and monitor service limits.

So, you will need to subscribe to Business Support.

For pricing, see: [Pricing for AWS Support Plans](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/pricing/)

Comment: We do have Business Support and we get a lot of checks, the only one that's disabled for us is "Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances Optimization"

Comment: I just checked mine, and it says: **This check is not available to accounts linked in Consolidated Billing. Recommendations are only available for the Paying Account.**